# Deleting SharePoint calendar links In Exchange via EWS

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Does anyone have examples of how to delete a user's SharePoint calendar link in Outlook/Exchange via EWS Managed API?   I am able to successfully find the Calendar link item, however the item.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete) executes without actually removing the calendar link.  Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Edited to include code:

```
    //Will target a specific user mailbox with parameter mbMailboxname
    static Dictionary<string, Folder> GetSharedCalendarFolders(ExchangeService service, String mbMailboxname)
    {
        Dictionary<String, Folder> rtList = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Folder>();

        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2018, 8, 1);
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2018, 8, 31);
        CalendarView calView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);
        Mailbox mb = new Mailbox(mbMailboxname);

        FolderId rfRootFolderid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, mb);
        FolderView fvFolderView = new FolderView(1000);
        SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Common Views");
        FindFoldersResults ffoldres = service.FindFolders(rfRootFolderid, sfSearchFilter, fvFolderView);

        if (ffoldres.Folders.Count == 1)
        {

            PropertySet psPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagWlinkAddressBookEID = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x6854, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagWlinkGroupName = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x6851, MapiPropertyType.String);

            psPropset.Add(PidTagWlinkAddressBookEID);
            ItemView iv = new ItemView(1000);
            iv.PropertySet = psPropset;
            iv.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Associated;

            SearchFilter cntSearch = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(PidTagWlinkGroupName, "Other Calendars");

            FindItemsResults<Item> fiResults = ffoldres.Folders[0].FindItems(cntSearch, iv);
            foreach (Item itItem in fiResults.Items)
            {
                Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item foundItem = itItem;

                if (foundItem.Subject.ToString().Trim().Contains("Company Group Calendar"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleting calendar..");
                    //Executing the delete command here does not delete the calendar
                    foundItem.Delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems);
                }
            }

        }

        return rtList;
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: Have you tried adding `foundItem.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete)` after your `MoveToDeletedItems` line?